# Unlock in game character by watching a video ad

Tags: java, android, ads

I would like to add a feature to my android game that would let the user unlock a character by watching a video ad. The games based on Java. How could I do this?

Comment: Follow some tutorial.

Comment: @DerGolem I didn't find any tutorials.

Comment: well i know for like for major ads for mobile, there are methods, that make you know if the ad has be closed, opened, showing.. yea, so based on logic you can really boolean boolean your way.. ayt..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Google Mobile Ads](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start), also known as AdMob. [Here is a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzTFkpIj2L4) to get you going.